# How to exclude some metric from metric_fu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metrics, metric-fu

I am using metric_fu 4.4.1

### my .metrics file says:

```
MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|  
 config.metrics -= [:reek]  
 config.metrics -= [:flay]  
 config.metrics -= [:flog]
end
```

### my metric_fu.rake says:

```
begin
  require 'metric_fu'
rescue LoadError
  puts 'Could not load metric_fu'
end
```

when i run: **bundle exec rake metrics:all**
get the fallowing error

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `metrics' for #<MetricFu::Configuration:0xa3d4f14>
/home/montells/Projects/beesor/.metrics:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/metric_fu-4.4.1/lib/metric_fu/configuration.rb:102:in `run'
/home/montells/Projects/beesor/.metrics:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/metric_fu-4.4.1/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:32:in `load_user_configuration'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/metric_fu-4.4.1/lib/metric_fu/run.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/metric_fu-4.4.1/lib/metric_fu/tasks/metric_fu.rake:5:in `new'
/home/montells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/metric_fu-4.4.1/lib/metric_fu/tasks/metric_fu.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => metrics:all
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I receive answer for this question via google groups.
[click here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/metric_fu/Qrk07uvudrE)

```
MetricFu::Configuration.run do |config|
  config.configure_metrics.each do |metric|
    if [:reek, :flay, :flog].include?(metric.name)
      metric.enabled = false
    else
      metric.enabled = true
    end
  end
end
```

and to price to Benjamin Fleischer